# Why this signed script take more time to execute than an unsigned one?

Tags: vbscript, code-signing-certificate, wsh

I have a signed VBScript. I am trying to execute it using `cscript.exe` through the command prompt. The unsigned script is executing faster (1 second) but if it's signed it's taking more time (16 seconds) to execute.

```
c:\cscript my.vbs
```

My .vbs file has the below content:

```
Wscript.echo "My very first script."

'' SIG '' Begin signature block
'' SIG '' BAcTCEVybGFuZ2VuMSAwHgYDVQQKFBdTaWVtZW5zIEhl
'' SIG '' YWx0aGNhcmUgR21iSDEgMB4GA1UEAxQXU2llbWVucyBI
'' SIG '' ZWFsdGhjYXJlIEdtYkgwggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUA
'' SIG '' A4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQC1y/VtChCaIT1wrPyyd6dyIiBv
'' SIG '' hwlw6P2ojQgyFutYPqGiPStdiA3O2cvrQJaaqu/lXc+v
'' SIG '' c3tOdSbg2YcqZg5Svpbhr7vxIiN7wd4DGKy8mFdpp23E
'' SIG '' UTnn9bcDqmEqNtLOfu3hFcyW760NDeXWPgwBvXqaUWUL
'' SIG '' kEr96LHmz0Zfohs0ER1WPgYkncIx14nd442KULJb8EyM
'' SIG '' nPvGbv9r4RROSqfGyNwV6EHnQ5TLHieE8n2o7lIEtMSP
'' SIG '' Ne1Psr7V2QEc9wZe2EEsTaKAwdTP3bhexoMK0dGTXcLf
'' SIG '' qI0IT3yqCou9X9zuYfpTmB0u0Mpi8Xma6OmO+L5UmXCo
'' SIG '' bBeXYJFvAgMBAAGjggFdMIIBWTAJBgNVHRMEAjAAMA4G
'' SIG '' A1UdDwEB/wQEAwIHgDArBgNVHR8EJDAiMCCgHqAchhpo
'' SIG '' dHRwOi8vc3Yuc3ltY2IuY29tL3N2LmNybDBhBgNVHSAE
'' SIG '' WjBYMFYGBmeBDAEEATBMMCMGCCsGAQUFBwIBFhdodHRw
.
.
.
.
etc
'' SIG '' End signature block
```

I am facing this issue only in machines which are in one network.

Comment: Extra size of the file `cscript.exe` has to open before the run-time can execute? It's not really rocket science to be honest, larger file longer to open. Having said that a difference of 15 seconds seems a lot.

Comment: @Lankymart Thanks for your reply. its not large file.it has only one statement, but it is signed. I know that signing is causing this problem. I dont know why is happening. I am able to reproduce this issue in only few machines.

Comment: The fact the file is signed means it contains more content then the first unsigned one hence the file size increases.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple really although a useful feature signing a script does introduce overheads.

1. It increases the size of the script file because encrypted signed hash has to be stored, while this shouldn't be an issue for small scripts it will have a significant impact on larger ones *(because the hash is created from the content)*.
2. The extra steps* taken to verify the encrypted signed hash when it is supported by Windows Scripting Host 5.6 or higher.

   1. Extract the certificate and signed hash from the script text.
   2. Verify that the certificate was signed by a trusted root, and hence is a trusted certificate.
   3. Decrypt the signed hash with the public key in the certificate.
   4. Compare the decrypted hash with the hash of the received script text.

*<sup>* Steps taken from [Windows Script Host: New Code-Signing Features Protect Against Malicious Scripts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb985985.aspx)</sup>*

> <sup>[Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40867109/why-this-signed-script-take-more-time-to-execute-than-an-unsigned-one/40884574#comment68975794_40867109) by OP</sup>
>   *I am able to reproduce this issue in only few machines.*

The likelihood here is those *"few machines"* take longer to verify the hash due to system limitations like processing power, memory or operating system load at the time the signed hash is being verified.